# Roots of two quadratic equations - why this approach?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Let $\alpha, \, \beta$  be the roots of the equation $x^2 - px + r = 0$ and let $\frac{\alpha}{2},\,\, 2\beta$ be the roots of the equation $x^2 - qx + r = 0$. Then the value of $r$ is one of the following.

$$\bbox[yellow, 5px]{(a) \,\frac{2}{9}(p-q)(2q-p) \qquad (b) \,\frac{2}{9}(q-p)(2p-q) }$$
$$\bbox[yellow, 5px]{ (c) \, \frac{2}{9}(q-2p)(2q-p) \qquad (d) \, \frac{2}{9}(2p-q)(2q-p) }$$

Now, I get the following equations for sum and product of the roots.

$$ \bbox[yellow, 5px] { \alpha + \beta = p } $$
$$ \bbox[yellow, 5px] { \frac{\alpha}{2} + 2 \beta = q  } $$
$$ \bbox[yellow, 5px] { \alpha \beta = r } $$

Manipulating them, I can see that answer is option (d)

$$ \bbox[yellow, 5px] { r = \, \frac{2}{9}(2p-q)(2q-p) } $$

But I had seen one video on youtube (its not in English), where the author of the video just chose $ \alpha =2 $ and $ \beta = 1$ and arrived at the values $ p = q = 3$ and $ r = 2$ and based on that he reasoned that the answer would be option (d). I want to know the reasoning behind this.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the author is just trying out some simple combinations to eliminate other three options

Comment: "I want to know the reasoning behind this": which of the two approaches do you call "this" ?

Comment: It's a simple way to approach thses sorts of multiple choice questions. Plug in random, simple values and see which answer makes sense. It avoids real mathematical manipulation but could be a faster approach to guarantee you the correct answer.

Comment: @Yves, I want to know why he is just choosing some numbers instead of using general approach

Comment: I guess since this question is from a competitive exam, so using such tricks is what is expected here.

Comment: In contest situations, it's often advantageous to try a test case. As for what might have motivated the particular choice ... Notice that (a) and (b) vanish when $p=q\neq0$, but (c) and (d) do not. This suggests that, if you could force $p=q\neq 0$, then the nature of $r$ would eliminate two choices. In particular, for $r\neq0$, we need only consider (c) and (d). Observe further that (c) and (d) are negatives of each other, so if we compute (c) and its sign matches $r$, we're done; otherwise, (d) is the solution w/o any extra work. (All that said, I would've solved like you did. :)

Comment: @Blue,  great insight. Using tricks is important in such exams. And these tricks also give further insight into the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the possible expressions of the solutions are given, it is "allowed" to try them with arbitrary values and if a single of them works, you are done.

This is because you have found counterexamples of the wrong expressions and as the correct expression is guaranteed to be there, you have found it by elimination.

Trivial example: is $8n-6$

- even,
- odd ?

If you plug $n=1$, $8n-6=2$ and you can conclude.

Comment: Thanks Yves!...